# Formatting Facet-Grid plot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I've created a facet graph (see picture below) and I would like to change the display so that the two variables ("final.score.new" and "total.score.r.new") are stacked together (one below each other for each id), instead of next to each other like below.

This is my current code:

```
  ggplot(data, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill=score_value)) + 
  theme_bw() + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) + 
  geom_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(id ~score_type) + 
  theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

Here is some example data:

```
data <- - read_table2("id   score_type  score_value ymin    ymax    freq    xmax    xmin
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   1   0
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   1   0
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   2   1
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   2   1
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   3   2
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   3   2
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   4   3
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   4   3
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   5   4
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   5   4
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   6   5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   6   5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   7   6
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   7   6
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 7.5 7
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 7.5 7
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 23  22.5
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 23  22.5
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 58.5    58
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 58.5    58
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   8.5 7.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   8.5 7.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   9.5 8.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   9.5 8.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   10.5    9.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   10.5    9.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   11.5    10.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   11.5    10.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   12.5    11.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   12.5    11.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   13.5    12.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   13.5    12.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   14.5    13.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   14.5    13.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   15.5    14.5
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   15.5    14.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   16.5    15.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   16.5    15.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   17.5    16.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   17.5    16.5
Adam    Ferari  2<=Rank<=10 0   0.01    1   18.5    17.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   18.5    17.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   19.5    18.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   19.5    18.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   20.5    19.5
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   20.5    19.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   21.5    20.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   21.5    20.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   22.5    21.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   22.5    21.5
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 7.5 7
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 7.5 7
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 23  22.5
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 23  22.5
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 58.5    58
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 58.5    58
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   24  23
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   24  23
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   25  24
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   25  24
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   26  25
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   26  25
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   27  26
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   27  26
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   28  27
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   28  27
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   29  28
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   29  28
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   30  29
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   30  29
Adam    Ferari  gameWin 0   0.01    1   31  30
Adam    Honda   gameWin 0   0.01    1   31  30
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   32  31
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   32  31
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   33  32
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   33  32
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   34  33
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   34  33
Adam    Ferari  gameLose_noCash 0   0.01    1   35  34
Adam    Honda   gameLose_noCash 0   0.01    1   35  34
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   36  35
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   36  35
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   37  36
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   37  36
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   38  37
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   38  37
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   39  38
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   39  38
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   40  39
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   40  39
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   41  40
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   41  40
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   42  41
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   42  41
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   43  42
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   43  42
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   44  43
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   44  43
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   45  44
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   45  44
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   46  45
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   46  45
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   47  46
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   47  46
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   48  47
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   48  47
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   49  48
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   49  48
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   50  49
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   50  49
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   51  50
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   51  50
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   52  51
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   52  51
Adam    Ferari  2<=Rank<=10 0   0.01    1   53  52
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   53  52
Adam    Ferari  2<=Rank<=10 0   0.01    1   54  53
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   54  53
Adam    Ferari  2<=Rank<=10 0   0.01    1   55  54
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   55  54
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   56  55
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   56  55
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   57  56
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   57  56
Adam    Ferari  gameWin 0   0.01    1   58  57
Adam    Honda   gameWin 0   0.01    1   58  57
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 7.5 7
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 7.5 7
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 23  22.5
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 23  22.5
Adam    Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 58.5    58
Adam    Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 58.5    58
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   59.5    58.5
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   59.5    58.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   60.5    59.5
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   60.5    59.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   61.5    60.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   61.5    60.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   62.5    61.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   62.5    61.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   63.5    62.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   63.5    62.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   64.5    63.5
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   64.5    63.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   65.5    64.5
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   65.5    64.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   66.5    65.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   66.5    65.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   67.5    66.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   67.5    66.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   68.5    67.5
Adam    Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   68.5    67.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   69.5    68.5
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   69.5    68.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   70.5    69.5
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   70.5    69.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   71.5    70.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   71.5    70.5
Adam    Ferari  2<=Rank<=10 0   0.01    1   72.5    71.5
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   72.5    71.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   73.5    72.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   73.5    72.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   74.5    73.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   74.5    73.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   75.5    74.5
Adam    Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   75.5    74.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   76.5    75.5
Adam    Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   76.5    75.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   77.5    76.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   77.5    76.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   78.5    77.5
Adam    Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   78.5    77.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   79.5    78.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   79.5    78.5
Adam    Ferari  gameWin 0   0.01    1   80.5    79.5
Adam    Honda   gameWin 0   0.01    1   80.5    79.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   81.5    80.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   81.5    80.5
Adam    Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   82.5    81.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   82.5    81.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   83.5    82.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   83.5    82.5
Adam    Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   84.5    83.5
Adam    Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   84.5    83.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   1   0
Sarah   Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   1   0
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   2   1
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   2   1
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   3   2
Sarah   Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   3   2
Sarah   Ferari  gameLose_noCash 0   0.01    1   4   3
Sarah   Honda   gameLose_noCash 0   0.01    1   4   3
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   5   4
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   5   4
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   6   5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   6   5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   7   6
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   7   6
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   8   7
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   8   7
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   9   8
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   9   8
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   10  9
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   10  9
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   11  10
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   11  10
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   12  11
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   12  11
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 12.5    12
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 12.5    12
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 32  31.5
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 32  31.5
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 45.5    45
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 45.5    45
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   13.5    12.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   13.5    12.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   14.5    13.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   14.5    13.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   15.5    14.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   15.5    14.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   16.5    15.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   16.5    15.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   17.5    16.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   17.5    16.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   18.5    17.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   18.5    17.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   19.5    18.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   19.5    18.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   20.5    19.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   20.5    19.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   21.5    20.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   21.5    20.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   22.5    21.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   22.5    21.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   23.5    22.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   23.5    22.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   24.5    23.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   24.5    23.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   25.5    24.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   25.5    24.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   26.5    25.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   26.5    25.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   27.5    26.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   27.5    26.5
Sarah   Ferari  gameWin 0   0.01    1   28.5    27.5
Sarah   Honda   gameWin 0   0.01    1   28.5    27.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   29.5    28.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   29.5    28.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   30.5    29.5
Sarah   Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   30.5    29.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   31.5    30.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   31.5    30.5
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 12.5    12
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 12.5    12
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 32  31.5
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 32  31.5
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 45.5    45
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 45.5    45
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   33  32
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   33  32
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   34  33
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   34  33
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   35  34
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   35  34
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   36  35
Sarah   Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   36  35
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   37  36
Sarah   Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   37  36
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   38  37
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   38  37
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   39  38
Sarah   Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   39  38
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   40  39
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   40  39
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   41  40
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   41  40
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   42  41
Sarah   Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   42  41
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   43  42
Sarah   Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   43  42
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   44  43
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   44  43
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   45  44
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   45  44
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 12.5    12
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 12.5    12
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 32  31.5
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 32  31.5
Sarah   Ferari  GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 45.5    45
Sarah   Honda   GameBreak   0   0.01    0.5 45.5    45
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   46.5    45.5
Sarah   Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   46.5    45.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   47.5    46.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   47.5    46.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   48.5    47.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   48.5    47.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   49.5    48.5
Sarah   Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   49.5    48.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   50.5    49.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   50.5    49.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   51.5    50.5
Sarah   Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   51.5    50.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   52.5    51.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   52.5    51.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank=1  0   0.01    1   53.5    52.5
Sarah   Honda   car2    0   0.01    1   53.5    52.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   54.5    53.5
Sarah   Honda   car3    0   0.01    1   54.5    53.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   55.5    54.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   55.5    54.5
Sarah   Ferari  gameWin 0   0.01    1   56.5    55.5
Sarah   Honda   gameWin 0   0.01    1   56.5    55.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   57.5    56.5
Sarah   Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   57.5    56.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   58.5    57.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   58.5    57.5
Sarah   Ferari  Rank>10 0   0.01    1   59.5    58.5
Sarah   Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   59.5    58.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   60.5    59.5
Sarah   Honda   car5    0   0.01    1   60.5    59.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   61.5    60.5
Sarah   Honda   car4    0   0.01    1   61.5    60.5
Sarah   Ferari  NA  0   0.01    1   62.5    61.5
Sarah   Honda   car1    0   0.01    1   62.5    61.5
")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

[image]

Would like to format it like so: 
[image]

Comment: I don't understand exactly what it is that you want. Could you give a rough sketch of what you'd like the final plot too look like? I can't figure out how you'd like to have the variables below each other.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is hard to understand how organize are your data and what parameters should be changed to get your graph.

Comment: Maybe you can play around with dodging?  Or using different ymin and ymax for your two score types so they won't be on top of each other?  I don't think anyone will be able to give a concrete solution with an example dataset.

Comment: @aosmith Added some sample data

Comment: The variables "final.score.new" and "total.score.r.new" are not in your current code or sample data.